# Query delay mouseenter

Tags: jquery, delay

How would I get the following code to delay for half a second before triggering the click event?

```
jQuery('selector').mouseenter(function() { jQuery(this).click() });
```

I tried adding .delay & setTimeout() but can't get them to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with `setTimeout`:

```
jQuery('selector').mouseenter(function() {
    var $elm = jQuery(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $elm.click()
    }, 500);
});
```

Note, though, that that will fire the click even if the mouse *leaves* the element within that half second. If you want to cancel the click if the mouse leaves the element, you have to remember the timer handle and cancel:

```
jQuery('selector')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        var $elm = jQuery(this),
            timer = $elm.data("timer");
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        $elm.data("timer", setTimeout(function() {
            $elm.click()
        }, 500));
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        var $elm = jQuery(this),
            timer = $elm.data("timer");
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $elm.removeData("timer");
        }
    })
;
```

That uses `data` to save a timer handle when the mouse enters the element, and if the mouse leaves the element, it cancels the timer. It's okay that we will cancel timers that don't exist (e.g., if the timer fires before the mouse leaves the element), that's a normal case, the `clearTimeout` call is just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you didn't realise that `setTimeout`, changes the `this` context. Your choice is to preserve the context with something like `bind` (an [ECMA 5 addition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind); if you need to support older browsers jQuery provides its own version of this via `.proxy()`)...

```
jQuery('selector').mouseenter(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { jquery(this).trigger('click'); }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

...or first store a reference to the outer scope (the element) in a var:

```
jQuery('selector').mouseenter(function() {
    var el = jquery(this);
    setTimeout(function() { el.trigger('click'); }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: The fact that `setTimeout` schedules an asynchronous action has nothing to do with the fact that `this` changes when you call a function.

Comment: True, now I think about it I don't suppose there's any reason why context couldn't be preserved for asynchronous events - it just never is.

Comment: @ Utkanos: Because of the callback, which involves a function call. ES6's arrow functions will preserve it (they have lexical `this` binding).